# HAProxy redirect based on the selected server

Tags: aws-lambda, google-cloud-functions, azure-functions, haproxy

I'm trying to setup HAProxy to change the destination URL depending on the Server that gets picked by the loadbalancer, I have 3 webservices each one deployed in each of the services AWS, GCP and AZURE

- The AWS is located at address1.com/service
- The AZR is located at address2.com/bucketName/service
- The GCP is located at address3.com/api/service

But in HAProxy I can't put a dash / on the server address to force a request made to example.com/helloWorld to go, for example, to address3.com/api/helloWorld, which is what I need, I want HAProxy to pick one of the servers for me using the balance method provided, and then have it calling the correct webservice depending on the server that was picked.

```
frontend example.com
    bind 0.0.0.0:80
    use_backend back_farm
    default_backend back_farm
backend back_farm
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    option httpclose
    option forwardfor
    server awsback address1.com/
    server azrback address2.com/bucketName/
    server gcpback address3.com/api/
```

I tried creating an ACL to check the selected server, but it doesn't seem to recognize the %s argument mentioned on the docs, and I've neither found a better replacement for it.

```
backend back_farm
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    option httpclose
    option forwardfor
    server awsback address1.com
    server azrback address2.com
    server gcpback address3.com

    acl is_azr %s -i azrback
    acl is_gcp %s -i gcpback

    http-request redirect code 301 location http://%[hdr(host)]%[url,regsub(^/service,/api/service,)] if is_azr 
    http-request redirect code 301 location http://%[hdr(host)]%[url,regsub(^/service,/bucketName/service,)] if is_gcp
```

What am I doing wrong in here, or what other way could I do this, to force the address to be changed depending on the destination server?
Any ideas or guidance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even throught this isn't 100% a reply to the question, because I had to switch from HAProxy to NGINX to be able to achieve what I intended, I wanted to leave the solution I found here for others that might find it usefull.

I was able to achieve this using the following configuration:

```
upstream backend.example.com {
    server aws.backend.example.com:8091;
    server azr.backend.example.com:8092;
    server gcp.backend.example.com:8093;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name backend.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend.example.com;
    }
}
server {
    listen 8091;
    listen [::]:8091;
    server_name aws.backend.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://address1.com:80/;
    }
}
server {
    listen 8092;
    listen [::]:8092;
    server_name azr.backend.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://address2.com:80/api/;
    }
}
server {
    listen 8093;
    listen [::]:8093;
    server_name gcp.backend.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://address3.com:80/bucketName/;
    }
}
```